# HTML div inside body with height 100% don't work

Tags: html, css

I've this CSS:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}


body {
    background-color: white;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.bodycontainer {
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-top:30px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

actually i can see the body with 100% height, but the div .bodycontainer is not set to 100% height.

Why?

Comment: can you show the markup? What's your doctype?

Comment: As you can see in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N7G9b/, your `<div class="bodycontainer">` is set to 100% plus 130px of padding. So you will need to post more of your code.

Comment: Its 100% :) check [LAB DEMO](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/previewProject/qeMeAcQZ~hDK9C3s!P0DxJaAQUiqK1kn)

Comment: Create a [**LAB DEMO**](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`
@Champ: i know it's set to 100%, because if i'm inspecting the div with the inspect element tool of firefox i can see the proporty height: 100%; but i disable it nothing happens. Don't understand;

Comment: div.bodycontainer is 100% + 130px tall, as morgul mentioned.
Does it show up in a different size to you? How tall do expect to see it? Probably you would need to add box-sizing:border-box to .bodycontainer

Answer (score 3):

Actually the total height of ".bodycontainer" is 100% + top padding + bottom padding

In order to make it exactly 100% height, use

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```